# Encrypting a XML file in Java with a password

Tags: java, xml, encryption, sha256, des

I'm doing this project for a client and the part i'm currently stuck on involves taking a XML String and encrypting it - this doesn't need to be state of the art, it just needs to encrypt it and decrypt it using a password.

So far the user enters a password which i've hashed using SHA-256, I then try and encrypt it by doing this:

```
public static String encryptString(String password, String source, String fileName, String fileDir) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeyException, FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    FileOutputStream fos = null;
    CipherInputStream cis;

    byte key[] = password.getBytes();
    SecretKeySpec secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(key, "DES");

    Cipher encrypt = Cipher.getInstance("DES/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
    encrypt.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey);

    InputStream fileInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(source.getBytes());//Here I am getting file data as byte array. You can convert your file data to InputStream  by other way too.

    File dataFile = new File(fileDir, fileName); //dataDir is location where my file is stored
    if (!dataFile.exists()) {
        cis = new CipherInputStream(fileInputStream, encrypt);
        try {
            fos = new FileOutputStream(dataFile);
            byte[] b = new byte[32];
            int i;
            while ((i = cis.read(b)) != -1) {
                fos.write(b, 0, i);
            }
            return fileName;
        } finally {
            try {
                if (fos != null) {
                    fos.flush();
                    fos.close();
                }
                cis.close();
                fileInputStream.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                //IOException
            }
        }
    }
    return "";
}
```

The password being passed in is the hashed password - from here I try and run it but I get a:

java.security.InvalidKeyException: Invalid key length: 64 bytes exception.

Can someone help please?

Or tell me of a better way to encrypt an XML file with a password?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the docs.

> If this cipher requires any algorithm parameters that cannot be
>   derived from the given key, the underlying cipher implementation is
>   supposed to generate the required parameters itself (using
>   provider-specific default or random values) if it is being initialized
>   for encryption or key wrapping, and **raise an InvalidKeyException if it
>   is being initialized for decryption or key unwrapping**. The generated
>   parameters can be retrieved using getParameters or getIV (if the
>   parameter is an IV).

A very simple way of encrypting is taking your hash and XOR it with the bytes in the file in a loop (256 bits at a time). It's kind of a low-level approach but you won't need to debug the API. You should be able to implement this with very minimal code.

Comment: Thank you for the help but I assumed the issue was that my SHA-256 key is generating a 64 character password and I only need a 32 for a DES encryption?

It might be simple but I'm not sure how to XOR a file..

Comment: Read in the bytes of a file in a loop. XOR the first byte with the first byte of the hash, the 2nd byte of the file with the 2nd byte of the hash, and so on. When you've looped through the hash, start again at the beginning. So the 9th byte of the file will be looped with the first byte of the hash. To decrypt, you use exactly the same process, XORing each byte of the file with a byte of the hash, in sequence. If that's not enough to get you started, I can provide some code.

Comment: @mttdbd I've love some code if you would be kind enough

Comment: Give me a bit and I'll post it on my Tumblr blog. You can find the link on my profile.

Comment: OK. I put up the code in a blog post. I want to be clear that this is not a secure method of encryption and I make no guarantees about its feasibility for any purpose other than to demonstrate how one would XOR a file using a hash.

Comment: Yes, but I did it using DESede instead of XORing it like you said.

Thanks anyhow.